# Make an entry to debugkit log

Tags: cakephp, logging, cakephp-debug-kit

The debugkit plugin is working just fine for me, but I cannot figure out how to make an entry that will show up in the toolbar`s Log tab (not Sql Log tab).

I`ve tried:
    DebugKit::write('log','got here');
..but it errors out with a 500.

...btw
    CakeLog::write('debug', 'Got here');
works just fine.

I feel kind of dubm asking this, but I can`t find any references.

Appreciate some wisdom here.

Shaun

Comment: Could you check logs for error details? CakePHP `error.log` (`tmp/logs` for CakePHP <= 2.x or `logs/` for CakePHP 3.x) and server logs if you don't find anything in CakePHP logs.

Comment: Hi Marian - here`s the text from the cake error log. as much as I could include......'2015-03-28 16:23:21 Error: Fatal Error (1): Class 'DebugKit' not found in [C:\Users\Shaun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\scheduling\app\Controller\IssuesController.php, line 27] 2015-03-28 16:23:21 Error: [FatalErrorException] Class 'DebugKit' not foundRequest URL: /issues/updaterecords.jsonStacktrace:#0C:\Users\Shaun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\scheduling\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(213): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(1, 'Class'DebugKit...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CakeLog::write('debug', 'Got here');`
and `DebugKit` will display it in Log tab.
Worked fine for me on `CakePHP 2.10`